# Executing Query takes time

Tags: acumatica

I have an extended table on Inventoryitem having 100 fields. I have written a smart search to show data based on the filter condition.

Item master having 25.000+ records

For fetching all the records it takes around 3 mins.

```
public PXSelectOrderBy<
        FilterResult, 
        OrderBy<
            Asc<FilterResult.inventoryID, 
            Asc<FilterResult.recordType>>>> records;

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[PXTable(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID),
   IsOptional = true)]
public class ItemExtendTable : PXCacheExtension<InventoryItem>
{

 }



[PXFilterable]
    public PXSelectJoinGroupBy<
        INSiteStatus, 
        LeftJoin<InventoryItem, 
            On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>>>, 
        Aggregate<
            GroupBy<InventoryItem.inventoryID, 
                Sum<INSiteStatus.qtyOnHand>>>> 
        item;
```

I am using the following statement to fetch a page data in the data delegate

```
protected virtual IEnumerable Records()
    {
        List<object> result = new List<object>();
        List<FilterResult> rows = new List<FilterResult>();
        PXView select = new PXView(this, true, item.View.BqlSelect);
        Int32 totalrow = 0;
        Int32 startrow = PXView.StartRow;
        result = select.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters,
               PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings,
               PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow);
        PXView.StartRow = 0;

        foreach (PXResult<INSiteStatus, InventoryItem> res in result)
        {
            InventoryItem item_rec = res;
            ItemExtendTable item_ext = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<ItemExtendTable>(item_rec);
            FilterResult ret = new FilterResult();

            // Fill values
            rows.Add(ret);
        }
        return rows;
    }
```

**

```
result = select.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters,
                       PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings,
                       PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow);
```

**

The above statement takes more than 3 mins to fetch data.

Using Extended table having impact on BQL query?

**Update**

I have run profile and it fires SQL Statement for each item. It fired more than 25000+ SQL Statement.

Comment: I believe you stumbled upon why they don't show all records at once. Remember, they have a layer between your code and SQL that translates your commands into SQL. That also takes time.

Comment: The issue with my DAC, I have used [Inventory(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DisplayName = "Inventory ID", IsKey = true)] in unbounded InventoryID Field.

Acumatica team helped to fix the issue and I have changed it to simple pxselector attribute